# Why does a mesh rotate over its own axis but Objects3D rotate over the world axis?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Here's some code as example:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( larguraX,altura,comprimentoZ);     
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: "pink"} );
var mmesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

var objj = new THREE.Object3D();
objj.add(mmesh);
...
```

Why isn't this:

```
mmesh.translateX(50);
mmesh.rotateY(Math.PI/2);
```

resulting just like this:

```
objj.translate(50);
objj.rotateY(Math.PI/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

They are the same.

Note the red and blue cubes are perfectly aligned making a purple box

```js
'use strict';

/* global THREE */

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 200;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(50, 0, 2);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 'red', transparent: true, opacity: 0.5,
  });
  const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 'blue', transparent: true, opacity: 0.5,
  });
  const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material1);
  const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material2);
  const obj = new THREE.Object3D();
  
  scene.add(cube1);
  scene.add(obj);  
  obj.add(cube2);

  cube1.translateX(50);
  cube1.rotateY(Math.PI / 2);

  obj.translateX(50);
  obj.rotateY(Math.PI / 2);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r94/three.min.js"></script>
```

you probably need to post more code

Comment: you're bloody right. 
Wt the heck. Thank you so much, I went step by step with your code and I finally understand this. Thanks :)